# how to replace content of div with new ajax result in ExtJs?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am new to ExtJs, I want to overwrite html content of Div id `"infraTab"` with new Ajax request result.

Help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
Below is the code what I am doing so far.

```
Ext.define('testview', {
    layout  :   {
                    type: 'border',
                    padding: 5
                },
    extend  :   'Ext.Panel',
    alias   :   'widget.infraTab',
    id      :   'infraTab',
    margin  :   '10 10 10 10',
    border  :   true,   
    items   :   Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
                    store: store,
                    tpl:resultTemplate,
                    itemSelector: 'div.list-item',
                    listeners: {
                        itemclick: function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                            getsublevels("abc");
                        }
                    }
            })
});
```

The above code is displaying the data, and the new ajax call function is

```
var getsublevels = function(value){

                        var sublvlStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                                                model : 'LevelModel',
                                                 autoLoad : true,
                                                    proxy : {
                                                          type : 'ajax',
                                                           url : 'Url',
                                                        method :'GET',
                                                        extraParams: {
                                                            test: test
                                                        },
                                                        reader : {
                                                                     type : 'json',
                                                                     root : 'data',
                                                            totalProperty : 'total',
                                                            successProperty: 'success'
                                                        }
                                                    } 
                                            });
                        sublvlStore.load();
                        Ext.define('testview', {
                            layout  :   {
                                            type: 'border',
                                            padding: 5
                                        },
                            extend  :   'Ext.Panel',
                            alias   :   'widget.infraTab',
                            id      :   'infraTab',
                            margin  :   '10 10 10 10',
                            border  :   true,
                            renderTo: "infraTab",
                            items   :   Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
                                            store: sublvlStore,
                                            tpl:resultTemplate,
                                            itemSelector: 'div.list-item',
                                            listeners: {
                                                itemclick: function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
                                                    getsublevels(record.get('value'));
                                                }
                                            }
                                    })
                        });
};
```

I tried `renderTo` but no luck.

Comment: I dont fully understand what your trying to acheive here, you shouldn't need to redefine testview for a start. Could you provide an explanation of what your trying to acheive and a sample ajax response would be handy for diagnosing the issue

Comment: The first block is displaying my result. Now once I click on any element from it then I am making new call and that result should be replace the original content.

Comment: just reload the original store, load with different params if needed. will load the new data and replace the list type view with new content

Comment: can you please guide me how to reload it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to replace the whole contents of the page for this, the list type view that you have is bound to the data in the store. You can update / change / reload or completely replace the data in the store and the results will be reflected on screen.

Try something like this in your top code block

```
items   :   Ext.create('Ext.view.View', {
     store: store,
     tpl:resultTemplate,
     itemSelector: 'div.list-item',
     listeners: {
         itemclick: function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
             store.reload({
                 params: {
                     parentValue: record.get('value')
                 },
                 url: '/new_url.php'
             });
         }
     }
})
```

In the above example when you click an item in the list, it will send an ajax request back to the server wtih a parameter containing the parent list item's value, to which your backend service should respsond with different data than the first request.

Comment: actually ajax URL call is not the same. Thus if I reload it then it'll call previous URL right ?

Comment: Yes it returns same format but data would be different. I have something like tree structure. Foldar1, Folder2, Folder3 getting display on page. If i click on Folder1 I am making new ajax url call to get sublevel which will return Foldar1.1, Folder1.2,Folder1.3 like this. But I want to show it on same page by replacing older content.

Comment: I have updated the answer, just update the url too / instead. [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gv8)